# Remove first of element pair with duplicate class. Classes have unique number for each pair

Tags: jquery, html

I have a pair of items with same class id number and I would like to remove first item of the pair.

```js
$('.itemid').each(function() {

    var currentclass = $.trim($(this).attr('class').replace('itemid', ''));

    if ($('.itemid.' + currentclass).length > 1) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemid 83"></div>
<div class="itemid 83"></div>

<div class="itemid 84"></div>
<div class="itemid 84"></div>

<div class="itemid 85"></div>
<div class="itemid 85"></div>
```

It is working great with plain HTML, but I can't get it to work on a live site. Could it be because div contains a lot of content and sub divs?

There are no jQuery errors and I can target items with a simple function like `.addClass` with no problems.

Another thing that crossed my mind - item number itself (83, 84, 85, etc) is generated by php. But I can target `$('.itemid.83').addClass('test');` with no problems

Maybe there is a better solution for this?

Comment: just a note for your last point: PHP being executed server-side, its code is never sent with the page. What is sent is the result of PHP. It is then perfectly normal that these numbers are in the page code, and accessible to javascript (which is executed on client side)

Comment: Do you have a live example that reproduces your behaviour? It's hard to fix the problem with your snippet because it works correctly..

Comment: There is a live example here `http://www.visit.jelgava.lv/en/sightseeing/castles-and-manors`. Jquery is located within `<div id="main-content"></div>`. There is a problem between two extensions at the moment and I needed a quick fix. This is probably one of the worst solutions, I imagine.

Comment: in your live example, when i type `$` in the console, mootools is showing up, not jQuery. That's why it is not working. Replace your `$` by `jQuery` in your code or wrap all this code in a IIFE like `(function($){ /*your code*/ })(jQuery);` if you want to keep $

Comment: I will try replacing `$` with `jQuery`, but I was using `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` is it not correct? Edit: I have changed `$` to `jQuery`, but unfortunately it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: i cannot confirm, passing an anonymous function to `ready` is correct, but i am not sure that it injects jquery as first parameter, never seen this syntax

Comment: I found it in Joomla documentation, if I recall correctly. I've been using a call like that on several occasions. For example `jQuery(document ).ready(function() {$('.itemid.83').addClass('test');});`works fine.

Comment: i don't know, it could also work because $ is global and not yet replaced by mootools.. anyway i can confirm that typing `jQuery('.itemid.83').remove();` in the console successfully removes the 2 correspondig elements from the page

Comment: Indeed it does, elements can be targeted by themselves, but I don't understand why the code isn't working. I wanted to remove just the first `.itemid.83` so second one remains. If it was just one pair of elements it would be easy, but there are other sections with format that I described in original question.

Comment: is it enough to make all this not work? for the number missing from the PHP execution, i think you should probably open a new question with the PHP code..

Comment: After some testing I found the problem. Code doesn't work since I have other classes in use, for example `<div class = "location_jelgava itemContainer col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 itemid 12"></div>`  how could I adjust jquery in order to get this working?

Comment: i could write you a solution easily if these were not number-only classes (which is not really recommended by the way, too generic). Do you know if you can configure your site to add a prefix to them? It would be easier to detect these classes. If not, tell me, i still can do it, it's just a bit trickier

Comment: Thank you for your patience! Would a class name like this be ok `itemid-81, itemid-82`? I can definitely do this. Unfortunately I do have to include some kind of numbering in class name but it can definitely doesn't have to be just number alone.

Comment: if you can, do it, it's always better, let me a little moment and i'll write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem coming from the fact that other classes can differ, we have to do some processing before we can select the good items. This code will be based on 2 assumptions:

`itemid` will be the primary class to select all the items (another class name can be used instead, but all elements will have this class, it will be much easier)

`itemid-{id}` will be the class identifying each item with a numeric id to find duplicates (again, another prefix can be used)

I have let the last duplicate not working on purpose, i had forgotten to add 'itemid-' at the beginning of the number, but it actually demonstrates that the code works well ;)

```js
$('.itemid').each(function() {
    
    //building an array of all classes
    var currentClasses = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    
    //extracting the class we want, there could be shorter methods but it's the end of the day here :p
    var i, l = currentClasses.length, stay = true, currentClass, found = false;
    for(i = 0; i < l && stay; i++){
        currentClass = currentClasses[i];
        //here a regex would be better, or else all classes beginning by 'itemid-' will be selected too
        if(currentClass.substring(0,7) === 'itemid-'){
            found = currentClass;
            stay = false;
        }
    }
    
    if (found !== false && $('.itemid.' + found).length > 1) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dummyClass itemid itemid-83">83</div>
<div class="differentDummy itemid itemid-83">other 83</div>

<div class="dummyClass2 itemid itemid-84">84</div>
<div class="differentDummy2 itemid itemid-84">other 84</div>

<div class="dummyClass3 itemid itemid-85">85</div>
<div class="differentDummy3 itemid 85">other 85</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much and especially for explaining the process!

Comment: It will help me to better understand this. Although I still didn't understand why first code didn't work just because div had many classes but this is yet another reason to learn jQuery!

Comment: you're welcome, it could probably be achieved with filter functions also, but it's always good to learn basic old school code too, after all, jQuery filter function would do something like this too probably. Basically your mistake was mainly to assume there was only 2 classes, only removing 'itemid' and spaces was not enough to form a valid unique class name ;)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

corrected remove only first element...

```js
   var more_slass_array=[];

   $('.itemid').each(function(){
        var current_class_array=$(this).attr('class').split(' ');
        for(var key in current_class_array){
          var current_class=current_class_array[key];
          if(current_class!='itemid'){
            if(more_slass_array.indexOf(current_class)==-1){
             more_slass_array.push(current_class);
            }
          }
        }
   });

   for(var key in more_slass_array){
      var current_class=more_slass_array[key];
      $('.'+current_class+':first').remove();
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="itemid 83">itemid 83 first</div>
<div class="itemid 83">itemid 83 next</div>
<div class="itemid 83">itemid 83 one more</div>

<div class="itemid 84">itemid 84 first</div>
<div class="itemid 84">itemid 84 next</div>

<div class="itemid 85">itemid 85 first</div>
<div class="itemid 85">itemid 85 next</div>
<div class="itemid 85">itemid 85 one more</div>
```

Comment: the code is just barely a bit worse and probably won't solve his issue (worse because there could be other elements with number classes like `83` etc. That would lead to a wrong count in this test: `if($('.'+this_other_class).length>1){`)